# cdrom mounting issues

Tags: cd-drive

This is my very first boot on ubuntu and I noticed the system did not open, pop up anything when I inserted a DVD. Researched a bit about and it seems ubuntu doesn't mount cd drives automatically, is that true or just for my case?

I tried some terminal commands and got the cd to mount. Is there a way it will behave like windows, and be there for me when I need it, with no need to play with terminal?

thanks for any help.

--Mezo

Comment: In ubuntu cdrom mounts automatically , ,you can see the cdrom icon on the launcher no need of external commands. Btw which command is ised to mount your cdrom?

Answer (score 0):

It normally defaults to auto-mount, auto-play, etc.  But you can change that.  For my system (Oneiric Gnome), in the "System Settings", "Removable Media", there are settings to "Select how media should be handled".  There is a button for "Other Media...", and includes blank disks, etc.  You can have it ask, do nothing, or run a program.

But I believe it normally will automount, although there is an option for whether it's visible on the desktop.  It should be available in the file manager, in the /media folder, though.